# How to create Material calendar in codenameone?

Tags: calendar, codenameone

Hi I'm new to Codename One and i did a sample on calendar but it showing normal calendar. i want to know how to implement Material Calendar in codename One?

If anyone have idea on this please suggest me some code

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you talking about Android Calendar widget?

Comment: yes.. is it possible ?

Comment: Diamonds answer is correct but if you just need to pick a date please notice the picker component which uses the native OS widget when running on the device see: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/spinner/Picker.html

Answer (score 0):

Codename One currently don't have such Calendar widget, but there's a classic matrix style Calendar which you can extend and customize as you like.

```
import com.codename1.ui.Calendar
Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. so how to apply/change the style of Calendar?

Comment: This customization is new and will be available by Friday plugin update. You can check out the pull request here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/pull/2214